# Wordpress Crash on long post content

Tags: php, apache, wordpress, xampp, wordpress-theming

I have a weird problem with my wordpress theme!
when i input a content in page content editor in wordpress's admin, if the content's height is more than `25 lines`, `apache server (xampp)` shows this error:

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version:  2.2.11.0
  Application Timestamp:    493f5d44
  Fault Module Name:    php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.2.9.9
  Fault Module Timestamp:   49a56925
  Exception Code:   c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 00151f0a
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.
```

what is the problem and how can i solve it?

P.S. `my page.php` file is this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
 <div id="middleDiv" >


<div id="pageDiv" align="center">

<div id="singlePageDiv" >

                <?php
the_post();

the_content();



    ?>

</div><!--singlePageDiv-->
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
    </div><!--pageDiv-->

</div><!-- #middleDiv -->
```

Comment: This sounds like a serious server configuration problem or bad installation of either Apache of PHP (probably PHP). Try reinstalling Apache, PHP or both. You versions of both are fairly old, try upgrading to PHP/5.2.17 and Apache/2.2.21. I would say upgrade to PHP/5.3.x, but on Windows it is frankly not worth the bother...

Comment: Nop, it still crash!
 `Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: httpd.exe
  Application Version: 2.2.21.0
  Application Timestamp: 4e6b3136
  Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll
  Fault Module Version: 5.3.8.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4e537a04
  Exception Code: c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 0018a7a3
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of my plugins caused that problem! :| Wp-Jalali